Does Google Account Recovery ever require BOTH a working recovery email and working recovery phone number?
Some members of Google Account community believed that:

Without BOTH a current recovery email AND a current phone number, previously set up in the account, (both must be accessible and up to date), then the account usually can't be recovered. -- 2022, Diamond Product Expert


When trying to Recover a Google Account, unless you have BOTH an accessible current recovery email, AND an accessible phone and current phone number previously set up in the account, the account usually can NOT be recovered. -- 2022, Gold Product Expert


To recover an account Google's automated system requires a current, accessible phone number/phone model, plus a secure recovery email address both of which have been registered to the account you're attempting to recover and are up to date. -- 2023, Diamond Product Expert.

However, these were replies to users who lacked "an accessible phone and current phone number previously set up in the account".
Question: Does anyone wish to provide evidence for the comments quoted above?
What I have tried
I asked the Google Account community.  My question has been locked for "not receiving a response" within 4 days.
In my original search of the Google Account community, I did not find posts from someone who had a working recovery phone number, but failed because they did not ALSO have "an accessible current recovery email".  This is despite the statements that this would "usually" be the case.

This post tries to answer the specific question above. If you are planning for Google Account Recovery, read the article from Google first: Avoid getting locked out of your Google Account.

In some cases, Account Recovery does require more than one verification step.  This includes cases where the first verification step was a code sent to your recovery phone.

In some cases, this additional verification can involve a code sent to a still-active Gmail login on one of your devices.  Let's call this "verification by Gmail".

So far, I do not have evidence that this additional verification can involve a recovery email address.

As a result, I do not have evidence that Account Recovery will "usually" require a working recovery email address AND a working recovery phone number.

Google Account and its Help Center strongly push you to add a recovery email address, as well as a recovery phone number.

Google appear to prefer recovery phone numbers over recovery email addresses.

As in my question, many users found they were not able to recovery their account, because they only had access to their recovery email, and Account Recovery did not allow them to use it.

If you are tempted to test Account Recovery yourself, please be very careful not to risk your main account, or make it harder to recover later.

In some tests, I have been able to perform Account Recovery using a recovery email (and not my recovery phone number).  This includes an account which also had a recovery phone number.  In other tests, I was not able to use the recovery email (at all).

If Google decide they do not like your recovery email address right now, they do not warn you about that decision.

Unpredictable variations between different cases are expected.  Account Recovery uses case-by-case risk assessments.  The system is not completely documented, because it is a security system, it is complex, and it will be tweaked over time.


My personal setup
I've been interested enough to set up a recovery email address using Outlook.com.  I have access to the recovery email inbox on my devices, and my devices will warn me if it breaks.
(I added the Outlook.com email inside the Gmail Android app.  To fix a "duplicate username" error in the Gmail Android app, I had to make sure that the "primary alias" of my Microsoft Account was not set to my Gmail address.)
My main reason for this is to receive copies of Google security alerts, in a second inbox where it will be harder to delete them or lock me out.
I don't seriously plan on using the recovery email for Account Recovery.  But having it makes Google happier.  Maybe it will be handy if Google detect "suspicious activity".  Or in some other case I am not aware of.
More detailed experiences and test results
Right now, I was able to complete the "forgot password" recovery process on my main account, using my recovery email (and not my recovery phone number).
However, I have not always been able to use my recovery email.
It might have refused to use my recovery email when I tested immediately after adding the recovery email.
Once, I had an account that looked like it had a recovery email, but then the recovery email section said I had not yet confirmed the recovery email address (using an email code).  I don't understand how this happened.  So, it might be worth double-checking in the sections for your recovery number and email, to make sure they have been confirmed!
Sometimes, Google has offered to send a recovery code to the same Gmail account that I am trying to recover :-).  (Call it "verification by Gmail").  This is deliberate.  Google believe that there is still a device logged in to your Gmail, which you may be able to access.  I feel this recovery method is intended to help save users who have 2-step-verification enabled.  If you do not have 2-step-verification enabled, you might not see it.
Google want me to have a recovery email.  When I have no recovery email on an account, Google Account shows an exclamation mark, amber warning, and that I should take action and add a recovery email.  I believe "Avoid getting locked out of your Google Account" also shows a warning, if you are logged in and have not added a recovery email.
Google advise the recovery email should be one that "you use regularly" - so not someone else's email.
Evidence from online reports
Cant access gmail as putted the same gmail in rrecovery mail.  "[I]t sends me the code to phone number.  I enter the code then it also tells me that i have to verify through recovery mail"
I think the above report confused "recovery by Gmail" (see above) with "recovery email address".  Because I think Google will not allow you to set the recovery email address to the Gmail address of your Google account.  I think people see the "recovery by Gmail" option, and then think their "recovery email address" has been set to their Gmail address.  I found another similar case of this.


There are an almost infinity number of conditions that could trigger additional verification or account recovery and Google has a large number of responses. It's impossible to say which is more important for all possible conditions (which is why you should have both), but in general, Google relies more on a phone than an e-mail. -- r/Gmail user with "Product Expert" flair

